# How to run Laravel Passport API in local machine?

Tags: php, laravel

I created a project with Vue in Laravel. I used Laravel Passport api. I copied this project to Xampp/htdoc folder. Then I create a new visual host for this project is "local.pos". My project in local.pos is running, the login form is show. After I type username and password, API will request to "localhost:8000/api/login". This address was not correct. It is should be "local.pos/api/login". I added an image for more information. Thank for help.

[image]

Comment: check your `.env(APP_URL)`, and what is the url that you are passing to your request?

Comment: Yes, It is http :// localhost

Comment: I changed http:/ /:localhost to http:/ /:local.pos, but it doesn't work.

Comment: when you made the change, you started the command php artisan config:clear ?

Comment: Yes, I used this command, but it still doesn't work.